# Is a power board really necessary for turtlebot? Or is an din-usb cable enough

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have an Roomba 780 and the din-usb communication cable from irobot, my question is if this is enough to enable communicate with the roomba with turtlebot? I realise that I will need to provide separate power for the kinect but wondering if there is something else special with the power board?

(at the moment it seems like turtlebot.eu is not selling any components so cant buy a power board for my roomba, I was thinking to make my own board with the schematics for the board but it appareas to me that the board is basically the usb interface with the FT2232RL chip and extraction of the 12v to the the user, is this correct?)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45207/is-a-power-board-really-necessary-for-turtlebot?-or-is-an-din-usb-cable-enough.../) by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krst](https://answers.ros.org/users/3315/krst/) on 2012-10-05**:
I cant see that the powerboard for the roomba has any gyro? Is it possible to read a gyro throught the din7 port of the roomba?

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-02-11**:
There is no analog input available on the Roomba, so no option to connect an analog gyro like the ADXRS613 directly. You could use another IMU device that is connected to the PC, e.g. with an USB interface. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Sensors/Pose%20Estimation#IMU for available drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not necessary if you have an alternate power source for the Kinect.  The other thing that it has is a small gyro which helps with the odometry, but there are parameters to disable the gyro for the software.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0